on screen keyboard is stuck on sticky key at login
The on screen keyboard is stuck in shift, so I can't login, I usually just login with the wireless keyboard, but can't because of this issue  I'm using windiest 10, any help at all appreciated.

Can't you double tab the shift to get it unstick?

"windiest 10" -- is that an alternate OS??
